# How to sum digits of a number untill there is one

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sum, digits

I want to solve this but I have no idea how to

I´d appreciate your help

given n take the sum of the digits of n if that value has more than one digit continue until there´s only one

Expected output:

```
16 -> 1 + 6 = 7
942 -> 9 + 4 + 2 = 15 -> 1 + 5 = 6
```

I tried this but I don´t know how to repeat it untill there is only one digit

```
Def sum_digit(n):
 list_of_digits = list(map(int,str(n)))

su = []
for x in list_of_digits:
x = sum(list_of_digits)
su = x

print(su)

sum_digit(6784)
```

Comment: What was the output when you ran this command, and what is "not working"? Also - what is your function returning? Why are you using a `for` loop here? If you can answer these questions, you'll come closer to your answer.

Comment: Indentation is semantically significant in Python. Your code fragment seems to have had its indentation stripped.  Nothing in your code deals with "until there is one".

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `while` loop to repeat until the number reduce to a single digit.

```
def sum_digit(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
    return n
```

---

```
sum_digit(16)
#7

sum_digit(942)
#6
```

Comment: @ArikyHito.. because all the numbers before 9 are single digit. Like `0,1,2,3..9`. After 9 they become double digits. So anything greater than `9 `should be added to make it single digit

Answer (score 6):

From this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99725/every-integer-is-congruent-to-the-sum-of-its-digits-mod-9), every integer is congruent to the sum of its digits mod 9.

Proof is easy:

`n ≡ sum_{k=0}^{m} 10^k d_k (mod 9) ≡ sum_{k=0}^{m} (9+1)^k d_k (mod 9) ≡ sum_{k=0}^{m} d_k (mod 9)`, when `m` = number of digits in `n` - `1`

Hence simply compute `n % 9` to find sum of the digits of `n` until one digit, without any loop / recursion.

```
def sum_digits(n): # assumes n > 0, otherwise n = 0 is trivial
    # assert(n > 0)
    return (n-1) % 9 + 1                # 1. this will work
    # return n % 9 if n % 9 else 9      # 2. this will also work
```

Comment: I think you have to put a condition when `n==9 return 9 else return n%9`

Comment: take example `18, 27, 36` any multiple of `9`. It should return `9` if you do `n%9` it will return `0`

Comment: @SandipanDey With a minor modification this will be very efficient. However, I think OP is really trying to understand how this can be implemented iteratively

Comment: @DarkKnight `(n-1) % 9 + 1` works for all `n > 0`

Comment: @SandipanDey That's fine but I still think you're missing the point of the question

Comment: @DarkKnight I would prefer a faster solution than more computationally expensive ones, just compare the time complexities

Comment: you are right @Goku `(n-1) % 9 + 1 ` resolves the issue for all `n>0` and it also does not need an `if-else` comparison

Comment: @SandipanDey ..yes now it is good

Comment: I believe that what @DarkKnight is pointing out is that this is clearly a novice question and almost certainly one that is not constrained by performance. Your solution, while elegant, is not illustrative nor helpful to someone who's level of python exposure might lead them to ask a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the sum of digits of the current number to a recursive call until it is a single-digit number:

```
def sum_digit(n):
    return sum_digit(sum(map(int, str(n)))) if n > 9 else n
```

so that:

```
print(sum_digit(16))
print(sum_digit(942))
```

outputs:

```
7
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting the value to a string and enumerating the digits (as suggested in other answers) is effective but slow. You can do it purely arithmetically as follows:

```
def sum_digit(n: int) -> int:
    while (_n := n) > 9:
        n = 0
        while _n > 0:
            n += _n % 10
            _n //= 10
    return _n
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function to sum the digits of a number until there's only one digit left.

```
def sum_digits(n):

   list_of_digits = list(map(int, str(n)))

   digit_sum = sum(list_of_digits)

   # If the sum has more than one digit, call the function recursively

   if digit_sum >= 10:
     return sum_digits(digit_sum)
   else:
     return digit_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Make sure you reinitialize the the `sum = 0` within the `keep_adding` function to make it forget the previously calculated sum.

```
digit = 9999999999999999999999999888
def check_length(x):
    if len(str(x))>1:
        return True

def keep_adding(digit):
    sums=0
    for i in str(digit):
        sums+=int(i)
    return sums

while check_length(digit):
    digit=keep_adding(digit)

print(digit)
```

I tried it on a few different values of `digit` and it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for efficiency.

**Here is my solution using recursion:**

```
def sum_of_digits(n):
    # Base case: if n is a single digit, return it
    if n < 10:
        return n
    
    
    digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(n)]
    
    # Calculate the sum of the digits
    total_sum = sum(digits)
    
    
    return sum_of_digits(total_sum)
```

## And the output

```
print(sum_of_digits(16))  # Output: 7
print(sum_of_digits(942)) # Output: 6
print(sum_of_digits(6784)) # Output: 5
```

Comment: An implementation using recursion can mean that your code is more concise but not necessarily efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a while loop to continue the summation process until the number is reduced to a single digit

```py
def sum_digits_until_single_digit(num):
    while num >= 10:
        total = 0
        for digit in str(num): 
            total += int(digit)
        num = total
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using **Recursion**:

```py
def digital_root(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        digit = n % 10
        total += digit
        n //= 10
    if total > 9:
        return digital_root(total)
    else:
        return total
```

```
print(digital_root(942)) # 6
```